# Remove columns that have only a unique value

Tags: r

I want to remove columns that have only a unique value.

First, I try it for a single column and it works:

```
data %/% 
  select_if(length(unique(data$policy_id)) > 1)
```

then I try it for multiple columns as below:

```
data %/% 
  select_if(length(unique(data[, c("policy_date", "policy_id"])) > 1)
```

but it does not work. I think it is a conceptual mistake due to my lack of experience.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `select(where())`.

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:5], B = 1:5, C = 2)

df
#>   A B C
#> 1 A 1 2
#> 2 B 2 2
#> 3 C 3 2
#> 4 D 4 2
#> 5 E 5 2
```

Then I can do:

```r
df %>% select(where(~ n_distinct(.) > 1))

#>   A B
#> 1 A 1
#> 2 B 2
#> 3 C 3
#> 4 D 4
#> 5 E 5
```

Comment: A more `dplyr-like` option would be `df %>%
 select(where(~ n_distinct(.) > 1))`.

Answer (score 3):

Some base R options:

- Using `lengths` + `unique` + `sapply`

```
subset(df,select = lengths(sapply(df,unique))>1)
```

- Using `Filter` + `length` + `unique`

```
Filter(function(x) length(unique(x))>1,df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:10,
+                  col2 = rep(10,10),
+                  col3 = round(rnorm(10,1)))
> df
   col1 col2 col3
1     1   10    1
2     2   10    0
3     3   10    1
4     4   10    1
5     5   10    1
6     6   10    0
7     7   10    2
8     8   10    1
9     9   10    1
10   10   10    1
> df %>% select_if(~length(unique(.)) > 1)
   col1 col3
1     1    1
2     2    0
3     3    1
4     4    1
5     5    1
6     6    0
7     7    2
8     8    1
9     9    1
10   10    1
>
```

Comment: I think it's best these days to avoid the `_if`, `_at`, and `_all` functions from `dplyr` given that the development team has moved on from those approaches. Taking me a bit to get used to the "new" way myself.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `purrr`:

```
df %>% purrr::keep(~all(n_distinct(.) > 1))
df %>% purrr::keep(~all(length(unique(.)) > 1))

df %>% purrr::discard(~!all(n_distinct(.) > 1))
df %>% purrr::discard(~!all(length(unique(.)) > 1))
```

Mixing `table` with `apply` generates the same output.

`df[, apply(df, 2, function(i) length(table(i)) > 1)]`

```
df <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:5], B = 1:5, C = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `base R`

```
df[sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:5], B = 1:5, C = 2)
```